# How do I populate an embedded document attribute on mongoDB Atlas?

Tags: mongodb

I've already successfully used an embedded document to create a nested `amenities` attribute, under a `spot` in my database, but now I'd like to populate it with true values. (by default they're false) The object that I created on mongoDB looks like this so far:

[image]

And on Postman, when I go to my `spots` index, this is what a `spot` looks like:

```
[
    {
        "amenities": {
            "wifi": false,
            "kitchen": false,
            "breakfast": false,
            "parking": false,
            "pool": false,
            "essentials": false
        },
        "_id": "5e4317871c9d440000b1613f",
        "name": "Test home 1",
        "latitude": 5.97,
        "longitude": 62.54,
        "city": "Los Angeles",
        "state": "California",
        "country": "United States",
        "description": "This is a test description",
        "occupancy": 4,
        "bedrooms": 2,
        "baths": 1,
        "date": "2020-02-11T21:20:28.969Z"
    }
]
```

How would I populate the `amenities` attribute on mongoDB? Do I need to add a line like this into the document on mongoDB?

```
amenities: { wifi: true, kitchen: true, breakfast: true, etc... }
```

Comment: *I've already successfully used an embedded document to create a nested amenities attribute* -- From that do you mean your document already had sub-doc `amenities` with false values & you wanted to update all values to true ? Or do you want to insert `amenities` to a document in spots collection (asking as I'm not seeing it in image) ??

Comment: I need help with inserting `amenities` into the document; I'd like to set some of them to true for this particular `spot` object, since by default all the attributes inside of `amenities` are false.

Comment: Still your question is not understandable !!  As if you're inserting `amenities` for the first time to a document why can't you form an object which few true & few false and finally `$set` that object into `amenities` field ?

Comment: I've never used mongoDB before/seeded the database with it before so I'm not sure how to set the `amenities` attributes for an object.

Comment: Can you give us the query that you use to `find` the needed doc ?

Comment: I've been using Postman to go to `/api/spots/` (on localhost) with a GET request and the output was what I posted above. And if I go to `/api/spots/:spotId` (also a GET request in Postman), I get all the same attributes above **except** for the `amenities` attribute.

Comment: check this :: https://codeburst.io/writing-a-crud-app-with-node-js-and-mongodb-e0827cbbdafb , If you need basics

Comment: Hm, I can't find anything about seeding the database in that guide...I've already done the routing and such; but now I'm trying to seed my database with a couple of `spots` so that I can see what the rendered output on the page looks like. And for that, I need some `spots` to have certain `amenities` (i.e. one spot can have wifi and breakfast, but another spot might only have wifi).